# How do I check if a string contains a number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check if a string contains a number. Any number.
Not wether or not the string IS a number, but if it contains one.

Examples:

'test' = no numbers.

'test2' = contains number.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using a [regular expression](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(testcol, '[[:digit:]]');
```

Not using regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE testcol LIKE '%0%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%1%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%2%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%3%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%4%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%5%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%6%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%7%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%8%'
    OR testcol LIKE '%9%'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the technique that I use to detect if a string contains a number:

```
select LAST_NAME, 'contains a number'
  FROM names
 where translate(LAST_NAME, '0123456789', '') <> LAST_NAME
```

That works by translating the digits to empty string.  If the string remains the same, then it could not have contained digits.

This technique also works to test if a string is all numbers

```
select TEL_NUMBER, 'is all numbers'
  FROM names
 where trim(translate(TEL_NUMBER, '-0123456789', '')) = ''
```

For the telephone number I included a dash because telephone numbers typically contain dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using regex. Like:

```
select regexp_instr('%[0-9]%',@str1) from table_name;
```

Cheers
--Jocke

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use REGEXP_INSTR in NetSuite saved searches since the SQL functions are limited.  It returns a zero if no numbers are found, or the starting position of the first number found in the string:

```
REGEXP_INSTR(my_var, '[[:digit:]]')
```

This example returns zero:

```
REGEXP_INSTR('test', '[[:digit:]]')
```

This example returns a number greater than zero since it found a number:

```
REGEXP_INSTR('test2', '[[:digit:]]')
```