# Query to restrict String field without numeric value that precedes or succeeds it

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query in oracle that restricts the below string values in a field unless there is a numeric string that precedes or succeeds it

```
"Department of" ,"Dept. of", "Dept Of"
```

For instance i want the Query to reject values like `"Department of"` ,`"Dept. of"`, `"Dept Of"` or even `"ABC Department of'` should not be considered but it can accept these values when a numeric string is present. For example `"Department of 1234"` or `"Dept. of 4567"` or `"2134 Dept. of"` or "`9864 Department of"` should not be restricted.

I am thinking of using REGEXP function but i am not able to come up with a query to handle the case of having NUMERIC that may precede or succeed the string value

I do not have data where numeric value is in between the strings `( "Dept. 21 of" )` so this case need not be considered.Finding if a numeric exists in the column will not help as the table has other records with numeric and data apart from the "Department of" ,"Dept. of", "Dept Of".

TIA.

Comment: try checking for existence digits from 0 to 9 in a given string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341492/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-number

Comment: @TheGameiswarthis one is different. OP mentioned ".Finding if a numeric exists in the column will not help as the table has other records with numeric and data apart from the "Department of" ,"Dept. of", "Dept Of"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(col, '[0-9] +(Dept. of|Department of|Dept Of)') or
      regexp_like(col, '(Dept. of|Department of|Dept Of)') +[0-9])
```

You can probably roll these into one regular expression, but I think two is easier to express.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using REGEXP, but, use the substring component to check the first (or last) value within the string you're searching from;

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

e.g;

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('2134 Dept. of',[0-9],1) "NumberPreOrPost" FROM DUAL;
```