# Performance optimized way to test whether a varchar field has any digit (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing a data validation across thousands of records.  I'm looking for a performance-optimized way to test whether a varchar field includes 1 or more digits.  For example, "MC KINNEY" is OK, but "MC KINNEY2" or "2MC KINNEY" or "MC123KINNEY" are not OK.

This test is to be used in the WHERE clause and has to work in SQL Server 2012.  I'm aware that the translate() function can be used in SQL Server 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424718 but this doesn't work in my case.

Comment: look into regular expressions

Comment: Using regex would've been overkill and a lot slower.  Using LIKE in Michael's answer is simpler and fast.

Comment: For my money they're the same thing. Looking up regular expressions in SQL yields several answers like Michael G provided.

Comment: If that solution runs long you may want to consider PATINDEX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052425/sql-string-comparison-speed-like-vs-patindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query using a ranged pattern expression:

**To Query for records with a digit:**

```
where fieldName LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

**To Query for records without a digit:**

```
where fieldName NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments for more information.